# Deserialize json to dynamic/anonymous class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

I have one concrete class called `ShipFromAddress` and where I am deserializing my json this below way

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
oShipFromAddress = jss.Deserialize<ShipFromAddress>(Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value);
```

**Concrete class**

```
public class ShipFromAddress
{
    public string Weight
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public string addressLine1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string addressLine2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string city
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string postcode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string countrycode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string StateCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I do not want to create or use concrete class rather I want to do that deserialization on the fly with the help of dynamic object or anonymous class concept. Please guide me with sample code.

### i got two solution.....which looks good

1) when need to pass multiple data serialize to anonymous the example would be

```
var query = from employee in employees select new { Name = employee.Name, Id = employee.Id };
LogEmployees(query);

public void LogEmployees (IEnumerable<dynamic> list)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in list)
    {
        string name = item.Name;
        int id = item.Id;
    }
}
```

method argument type must be `IEnumerable<dynamic> because LogEmployees()` function expecting multiple data

2) when passing single data the code look like

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Thing(dynamic other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(other.TheThing);
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var things = new { TheThing = "Worked!" };
        Thing(things);
    }
}
```

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JavaScriptSerializer you can use the `DeserializeObject` method from serializer which will return just an object:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object obj= jss.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value);
```

Internally it will be represented as a `Dictionary<string, object>`, so you can cast it to it and use like this:

```
var values = (Dictionary<string, object>)jss.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value);
var addressLine1 = values["addressLine1"].ToString();
```

Or you can cast it to `dynamic`:

```
dynamic values = jss.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value);
var addressLine1 = values["addressLine1"].ToString();
```

*Alternatively*, You can use `Json.NET` library and it's `JsonConvert` class (benchmarks show that it performs faster than `JavaScriptSerializer`). The code will look like this:

```
dynamic values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value);
var addressLine1 = values.addressLine1;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a strongly typed object.

Comment: you might want to declare `obj` as dynamic, which is more useful here, and in general `JavaScriptSerializer` is a bad idea - use `JsonConvert` from Json.NET - that's faster and less buggy.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne added a note regarding Json.NET

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov OP states that he wants to deserialize the object into dynamic structure, not a concrete class

Comment: dynamic as the `dynamic` type?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think so :)

Answer (score 3):

I use Newtonsoft.Json

```
string source = Request.Cookies["ShipFromAddress"].Value as string;

var address = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShipFromAddress>(source);
```

Comment: address1,address2,city, postcode etc all will be stored in address variable? can we access like address.addressLine1 or address.City ?

Comment: you can access it like as an objecto of the class ShipFromAddress
address.City , address.addressLine1 ,  etc